# Topbar design is out of date

Tags: bug, design

Ubuntu redesigned their website, meaning Ask Ubuntu's top bar is out of date.

[image]

[image]

Note how the top bar "jumps" about:

[image]

Comment: what are you proposing they change, exactly?

Comment: @Seth use the same code for the positioning? I'm not sure, but it should be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping around is probably inevitable: SE sites have fixed width 1100px, while Ubuntu site (which is now responsive) has width 984px at most. The recent widening of the SE sidebar has increased the difference.

One thing that could be done to improve consistency is to add **Partners** link to the SE version of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the top bar is out of date, but for a completely different reason:

I am active on several stackexchange sites, and the positioning of the menue items is different on the other stackexchange sites. I think consistency with the other stackexchange sites would increase usability.

Comment: No, this site is part of the Ubuntu.com site - and you should be able to access other parts from here too.